# Selecting child elements based on parent conditions while handling nulls using JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to filter my JSON object using Newtonsoft with `JToken`s. I need to select child elements in an array based on a condition on the parent element. Also, the array that will be filtered may have null child elements.

Here is the JSON object:

```
{
    "level1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "level2": [{
                "attr": "attrvalue"
            },
            {
                "attr": "attrvalue",
                "level3": [{
                        "attr1": "attr1value",
                        "level4": [{
                            "filterAttr": ["val1"],
                            "attr1": "attr1value"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "attr1": "attr1value",
                        "level4": [{
                            "filterAttr": ["val1"],
                            "attr1": "attr1value",
                            "level5": [{
                                "key": "key",
                                "value": "value"
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I am using the code below as of now to filter the above JSON. I need to get the `key` and `value` from `level5` based on `filterAttr` in `level4` that has `val1`.

```cs
var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

var key = jToken["level1"]
    .SelectMany(x => x["level2"])
    .Where(x => x["level3"] != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x["level3"])
    .Where(x => x["level4"] != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x["level4"])
    .Where(x => Convert.ToString(x["filterAttr"]) == filterParam && x["level5"] != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x["level5"])
    .Where(x => Convert.ToString(x["key"]) == keyParam)
    .Select(x => x["value"])
    .First().ToString();
```

Is there a better way to check for nulls than what is written above? 
Is there a better way to filter on a parent attribute and get the child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a couple of techniques to simplify your code.

1. Use `SelectTokens()` with a wildcard expression to drill down to the lowest level.  `SelectTokens` automatically handles nulls, so if a node is missing somewhere along the path, it will not blow up.  You will get items that match the whole expression or an empty enumerable if there are none.
2. Create extension methods to help with null checking and use those in your queries.  For example, you can make a method which will check if a `JToken` is null, and if not, then check whether it has any children matching some condition.  e.g.:

   ```
       public static class JsonExtensions
       {
           public static bool HasAny(this JToken token, Func<JToken, bool> predicate)
           {
               return token != null && token.Children().Any(t => predicate(t));
           }
       }
   ```

Putting these ideas together you could do this:

```
string key = jToken.SelectTokens("level1[*].level2[*].level3[*].level4[*].level5[*]")
    .Where(x => (string)x["key"] == keyParam &&
                x.Parent.Parent.Parent["filterAttr"].HasAny(y => (string)y == filterParam))
    .Select(x => (string)x["value"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above code drills down to select all children of `level5` having a `key` matching the `keyParam`.  It then walks up the chain from there to `level4` to see if the `filterAttr` has any children matching the `filterParam`.  (We need three `.Parent`s here because the parent of the object containing the `key` property is the array, the parent of the array is the property `level5`, and the parent of that property is the object containing the `filterAttr`.)  If there are any items meeting the conditions, we return the first `value` from those.

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/45M23h

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Is there a generic way to handle this? like looping down all the elements until i find the key and check if any parent has the filterAttr?

Comment: So you are saying that the `key` can be at any level, not just `level5`, and the `filterAttr` can be at any level above that?

Comment: I mean lets say if this is the structure and i have another completly different one but i write a generic method where i pass in key and filter predicate and get the value of passed in key? The filter tht will be passed will have the hierarchy defined.

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want to be able to search downward and upward through the hierarchy.  If you parse your JSON to a `JObject` you can use the `Descendants()` and `Ancestors()` extension methods to help with this.  Maybe [something like this is](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iK0Z8g) what you are looking for?

Comment: No, so i what i am looking for is to have a method that will accept first param as key i.e. "key1" and 2nd as the filter like "level1/level2/level3/level4['filterAttr'] = 'filterParam'" and my method will do the filtering based on this and find the first matching key1 from the results.

Comment: the 2nd example is close but it is trying to search just the key and if it find at any level it will pick it up. Why i want the filter with a hierarchy is because the JSON object that is an array can have the filter param at multiple levels.